# Add linked libraries relative to a custom location in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 9 to build a project that requires linking against a large number of standalone libraries (.a and .dylib files), which are all located in an arbitrary directory outside of my project.

I can build if I manually add all these libraries to Linked Frameworks and Libraries, but then I am hardcoding a relative path to this arbitrary directory.

Is there a way to add libraries to Linked Frameworks and Libraries list, but add them as paths relative to a user-defined location, perhaps a location specified as a User-Defined Build Setting?

To be specific, I have an environmental variable `G3D` which specifies a path. All these libraries are off of `$G3D/build/libraries`. But after adding the libraries to my project by dragging and dropping them, the File Inspector only lets me specify their location as being Relative to Group, Relative to Workspace, etc..

It’s possible to specify libraries relative to an arbitrary variable if I opt out of the Linked Frameworks list entirely, and specify all the link libraries using the Other Linked Flags Build Setting, but that introduces its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your Framework Search Paths in build settings, you are allowed to refer to your user-defined build setting...  e.g. say you have a user-defined build setting REALM_PATH which specifies some portion of a path.

Then in your Framework Search Paths build setting, you can add some path and insert REALM_PATH by putting ${} around it.  E.g.

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/../../External/ThirdParty/submodules/${REALM_PATH}
```

Comment: But when I add an item to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, and it raises its picker control that lets me select built-in frameworks or arbitrary locations, will it now show and let me select libraries and frameworks which are on the framework search path only because of that user-defined setting?

Comment: I don't think so.  I found myself in this same situation just last week.  I wound up simply dragging the framework from the project navigator pane directly into the Linked Frameworks and Libraries build phase.  It worked just fine.

Comment: But does this not define your project so that it now has hardcoded project-relative paths to those libraries, rather than, for instance, REALM_PATH-rooted paths?